# Getting wrong when i use x:bind in uwp: invalid binding path err

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I try to use x:bind function to display String which using String.Concat() to connect two string. I follow the instruction from this website: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/function-bindings

Since this is the first ask question on Stack Overflow, if the way i ask was wrong, please point it out. thanks (≧∀≦)ゞ

I tried using System.Contact() in the function i created in another namespace and its look good.

```xml
xmlns:sys="using:System"
xmlns:local="using:uwpppp.Scenes.ReciteF">

...

<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind sys:String.Concat('hello','123')}"/><!--not good-->

<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind local:Showdetail.GetString('hello','hello2')}"/><!--good-->
```

```cs
public static String GetString(string a, string b)
{
    return String.Concat(a, b);
}
```

Invalid binding path 'sys:String.Concat('hello','123')' : Function parameter '1' is invalid or mismatched

Comment: I get the same problem. It works when I use a function from my own class but not when using System.

Comment: This is a bug within UWP and is yet to be rectified. You'll find this out with a lot of features in UWP.

What is it that you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/function-bindings), I think the problem lies in this point:

> Overloading is based on the number of arguments, not type, and it will try to match to the first overload with that many arguments

`String.Concat` has many different overloads and the `x:Bind` mechanism most likely first finds the `(object,object)` overload and that causes the error you are seeing:

```
Invalid or missmatched parameter at position '1'.
```

In case of your custom method, you have only one overload so it can clearly use the `(string, string)` parameters.

Comment: Ok，i will use custom method in different name to avoid this problem, thanks!

Comment: It doesn't work for me with 1, 2 or 3 parameters, but this works: <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind sys:String.Concat('hello','123','999','888')}"></TextBlock>

Comment: Very unusual. But I guess in this case it finds the `string` overload before four `objects`

Comment: If the answer helped, please consider marking the answer as solution so that the question is closed :-)

Comment: This was also hitting for me with `{x:Bind MyControl.SomeBoolValue.Equals(x:False), Mode=OneWay}`. I think it was hitting the `object` overload before the `Boolean` overload (though I'm not sure). Thanks for this!